# White outline around advertising (UWP app)

Tags: uwp, windows-10, ads, uwp-xaml, windows-dev-center

I'm developing an application (UWP), and was finishing and placing advertising. When I test, a white outline appears:

[image: http://imgur.com/abbmjra.png]

This is my code:

```
<UI:AdControl ApplicationId="3f83fe91-d6be-434d-a0ae-7351c5a997f1"
              AdUnitId="test"
              RelativePanel.AlignTopWithPanel="True"
              RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True"
              Margin="0,25,0,0"/>
```

This is normal?

Comment: Does this happen with every ad? It could just be part of the ad image.

Answer (score 0):

> This is normal?

The outline should be normal though I'm not sure about the specific cause. I have checked your code without problem.

Additionally, you'd better test it with the real value. Maybe the outline will disappear after you publishing your app as it can request for different ads.

Please note that the real `ApplicationId` and `AdUnitId` value should apply from the published apps and it takes 1-2 days after that for ads from real units to start serving.